# Represent ${f(x) = \arctan(x) + x\ln(4+x^2)-x(1+\ln(4))}$ by a Maclaurin series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I have the following problem:
Represent the function:

$${f(x) = \arctan(x) + x\ln(4+x^2)-x(1+\ln(4))}$$ by a Maclaurin series.

I do not know how to represent this part: ${x\ln(4+x^2)}$

Could you please help me?

Comment: Is $X$ the same as $x$?  If not, what is it?

Comment: Do you know a series for $\ln(1+z)$? If so, how could you modify it into the one you want by substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so notice that

$${\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^n}{n}}$$

which converges for ${-1<x\leq 1}$.

We can write ${\ln(4+x^2)=\ln\left(4\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right)=\ln(4)+\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}$. Replace $x$ with ${\frac{x^2}{2}}$, and you get

$${\ln\left(4+x^2\right)=\ln(4)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{n\times 2^n}}$$

And this will converge for ${0 \leq \frac{x^2}{2}\leq 1\Leftrightarrow -\sqrt{2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{2}}$. Now, just multiply both sides by ${x}$ to get your expansion for ${x\ln(4+x^2)}$.

Notice as well the ${x\ln(4)}$ will cancel out in the end result for ${f(x)}$. I found it odd that that term was just lurking around, but it makes sense now. Your teacher probably just wanted to cancel out the awkward term at the front